# How to "replace" an item inside an ember array as of 1.0

Tags: ember.js

In ember.js RC5 I was able to replace 2 elements inside an array of ember objects like so

```
appointments.replace(starting-index, number-of-elements-to-remove);
```

but today that doesn't actually "splice out" the elements as it did pre ember 1.0

If I try to hack it and splice the array myself like so, it does nothing (no error either)

```
[].concat(appointments).splice(starting-index, number-of-elements-to-remove);
```

Anyone know how to remove / replace elements from a list of ember objects as of 1.0?

**Update**

The ember inspector shows the model type as DS.RecordArray (using the latest ember-data 1.0 beta 3)

I tried the removeAt but it still doesn't work sadly

This is how I populate the array in my app

```
var appointments = self.store.all('appointment');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely still works, are you sure it's an ember array?  Or is this an Ember Data RecordArray?

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aKonIk/1/edit

Oh, the real issue is store.all.  It is a filtered record array.  One of the special properties of Filtered Record Arrays is they are live, meaning they stay up to date.  Filtered RecordArray:

> ** Takes a type and filter function, and returns a live RecordArray that remains up to date as new records are loaded into the store or created locally.

Meaning as you remove the records, they probably are getting reinserted.

I'll test this out, but I'm pretty sure it will always stay up to date with the latest records in the store, so you'd either need to copy the records to a different array, or delete the records from the store.

**Update**

It appears it still works as well (at least in my simplistic example below)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uHiCAc/3/edit

Comment: thank you for the detailed feedback! I finally got a working version of this (but had to punt on doing it inline -ended up with a vanilla JS array that I filter before getting ember-data involved)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `removeAt` instead?

It has the same signature as you need `removeAt(start, length)`.

See here http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_removeAt

Hope it helps.